# How can I stop Windows 10 Home 64-bit from suddenly rebooting without warning?

Tags: windows-10-v1709

I am running Windows 10 64-bit Home Version 1709, OS Build 16299.248.
Processor is AMD A10-5800K APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics 3.80 GHz
Installed RAM 8.00 GB (7.20 GB usable)

Installed this new Windows 10 about 6 weeks ago, and ever since I have been having this problem.

I can be working merrily along with two or three apps running, such as Google Chrome, MS Edge, and a large Excel spreadsheet (70,000+ rows).  Everything is working fine and I am saving the Excel file regularly.

SUDDENLY the system reboots without warning.  I don't really  lose anything... it is just the time delay and inconvenience that bothers me.

I have read many articles on the web about this problem; evidently many folks are having the same problem.  Yet, even though I have tried all of their solutions, the problem remains.

Does anyone have any accurate advice to solve this?  I really would appreciate hearing.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your system is actually crashing.  Even Windows 10 Home allows you to schedule when an update is installed, so updates not being installed, which is what most people are complaining about when they talk about "sudden reboots" with Home editions.

Comment: look in eventlog for event 41 entries and look for possible causes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: Numerous Error 41 (Task Category 63).  All say:

"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first.  This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

Source:  Kernel-Power

Keywords:  (70368744177664),(2)

My settings for Power & Sleep:  Screen:  Never  Sleep:  Never

Power Plan:  Balanced

I just now changed the above settings to the default:  Screen:  10 minutes  Sleep:  30 minutes.

I'll see what happens now.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: probably solved, thanks to magicandre1981 !!  It appears that resetting the Power and Sleep settings to DEFAULT cured the recurrent shutdowns, as I have had no more since the reset on Feb 16  That was 8 or 9 days ago.  I appreciate the interest and help from everyone.